# Finding the subset of non-overlaping sequences with highest score

Tags: optimization, sequence, bioinformatics

Let's have a set of sequences with given start, end and score (not lenght). What is the best way to find a subset of sequences which gives the highest score? For better understanding here is the example, where we have a set of 3 sequences:

[image]

The output of algorithm should be this two subsequences with score 115:

[image]

Assume there will be milions of subsenqences and the time for completition should be maximum of tens of minutes on computer with 8GB ram.

Comment: The problem has optimal substructure (this is a big hint!), and is generally known as _weighted job scheduling_.

Comment: There is one more problem, the input data will not be sorted, I can not simply load it and then sort it because of its size.